# CameraX controller zooming not smooth

Tags: java, android, android-activity, camera, android-camerax

I use [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) API for handle camera in my application, and I added `SeekBar` to control zoom camera, but it not working well when I seek to 0 it was zoom out then I seek to 100 it zoom to maximum amount, so what I need to do, zoom 0 - 100 zooming smoothly

**Current Preview**

[image]

**CameraActivity.java**

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
private int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 1001;
public static final int REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE = 1002;
private final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{"android.permission.CAMERA", "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};

private PreviewView mPreviewView;
private FloatingActionButton captureImage;
private VerticalSeekBar seekBar;
private Camera camera;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    mPreviewView = findViewById(R.id.camera);
    captureImage = findViewById(R.id.capture);
    seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);


    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            camera.getCameraControl().setLinearZoom((float) (progress/100));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
    if(allPermissionsGranted()){
        startCamera(); //start camera if permission has been granted by user
    } else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
    }
}

private void startCamera() {

    final ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                bindPreview(cameraProvider);

            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                // No errors need to be handled for this Future.
                // This should never be reached.
            }
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
}

void bindPreview(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {

    Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
            .build();

    CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
            .build();

    ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .build();

    ImageCapture.Builder builder = new ImageCapture.Builder();

    //Vendor-Extensions (The CameraX extensions dependency in build.gradle)
    HdrImageCaptureExtender hdrImageCaptureExtender = HdrImageCaptureExtender.create(builder);

    // Query if extension is available (optional).
    if (hdrImageCaptureExtender.isExtensionAvailable(cameraSelector)) {
        // Enable the extension if available.
        hdrImageCaptureExtender.enableExtension(cameraSelector);
    }

    final ImageCapture imageCapture = builder
            .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
            .build();
    preview.setSurfaceProvider(mPreviewView.getSurfaceProvider());

    camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis, imageCapture);
    camera.getCameraControl().setZoomRatio(0.1f);


    captureImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
            File file = null;
            if(path != null){
                file = new File(path, getIntent().getStringExtra("fileName"));
            } else {
                SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.US);
                file = new File(getBatchDirectoryName(), mDateFormat.format(new Date()) + ".jpg");
            }
            ImageCapture.Metadata metadata = new ImageCapture.Metadata();
            if(Session.getLocation() != null) {
                metadata.setLocation(Session.getLocation());
            }
            ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions = new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(file).setMetadata(metadata).build();
            File finalFile = file;
            imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, executor, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback () {
                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("path", finalFile.getPath());
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Image Saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

public String getBatchDirectoryName() {

    String app_folder_path = "";
    app_folder_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/images";
    File dir = new File(app_folder_path);
    if (!dir.exists() && !dir.mkdirs()) {

    }

    return app_folder_path;
}

private boolean allPermissionsGranted(){

    for(String permission : REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS){
        if(allPermissionsGranted()){
            startCamera();
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions not granted by the user.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            this.finish();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try to make a one field to allocate camera.getCameraControl(), ex) cameraControl / so you can call cameraControl.setLinearZoom((float) (progress/100)); on onProgressChanged

Comment: you mean assign `camera.getCameraControl()` to new field then use it on `onProgressChanged` ?

Comment: Right, I guess calling a ``camera.getCameraControl()`` costs a lot.

Comment: but it takes same instance, anyway approach is not matter, I need to find solution for the case, we can optimize it later on, do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: Sorry :( I can help anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You are casting the value incorrectly. So instead:

`camera.getCameraControl().setLinearZoom((float) (progress/100));`

do:

`camera.getCameraControl().setLinearZoom((float) progress/seekBar.getMax());`

Comment: `seekBar.getMax()` yes you right for some of the way, but it's not for the answer to my question, because in `seekBar.getMax()` return 100

Comment: The reason you get 0 -> 1 directly is that you can doing the division before casting to float. You need to cast it to float first then divided by the max value. Using getMax is just good code health, which is not directly related to your issue.

Comment: thanks, I couldn't see it that way, code can be tricky sometimes